# nginx and php5-fpm: missing end of LSB comment

Tags: php, nginx, raspberry-pi, raspbian, fpm

I am running nginx/1.2.1 on a raspberry pi (raspbian wheezy).
Since a few days, I see a problem probably in relation to php5-fpm: The server gives a 502 error code (bad gateway) whenever a php site is called; html is working fine.
So, I tried to upgrade old packages including the php5-fpm but this failed with the same error I will descibe below.

After fiddling around with updating other old packages, I made a backup of nginx and wanted to do a clean re-install. However, even removing nginx fails with the following output that was also given when I tried to update php5-fpm:

```
me@computer /etc/nginx $ sudo apt-get remove nginx && sudo apt-get install nginx

Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
AbhÃ¤ngigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benÃ¶tigt:
  geoip-database libgeoip1 libmysqlclient16 nginx-common nginx-full
Verwenden Sie Â»apt-get autoremoveÂ«, um sie zu entfernen.
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  nginx
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 1 zu entfernen und 5 nicht aktualisiert.
10 nicht vollstÃ¤ndig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 89,1 kB Plattenplatz freigegeben.
MÃ¶chten Sie fortfahren [J/n]? J

(Lese Datenbank ... 84062 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Entfernen von nginx ...
mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.58-0+deb7u1) wird eingerichtet ...
[ ok ] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
insserv: Script nginx is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurÃ¼ck
php5-fpm (5.4.45-0+deb7u11) wird eingerichtet ...
insserv: Script nginx is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von php5-fpm (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurÃ¼ck
rpcbind (0.2.0-8+deb7u2) wird eingerichtet ...
insserv: Script nginx is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von rpcbind (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurÃ¼ck
memcached (1.4.13-0.2+deb7u3) wird eingerichtet ...
insserv: Script nginx is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von memcached (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurÃ¼ck
dpkg: AbhÃ¤ngigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von mysql-server:
 mysql-server hÃ¤ngt ab von mysql-server-5.5; aber:
  Paket mysql-server-5.5 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von mysql-server (--configure):
 AbhÃ¤ngigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
nginx-common (1.2.1-2.2+wheezy4+deb7u1) wird eingerichtet ...
update-rc.d: warning: default start runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match nginx Default-Start values (! 2 3 5")
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match nginx Default-Stop values (none)
insserv: Script nginx is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von nginx-common (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurÃ¼ck
dpkg: AbhÃ¤ngigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von nginx-full:
 nginx-full hÃ¤ngt ab von nginx-common (= 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy4+deb7u1); aber:
  Paket nginx-common ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von nginx-full (--configure):
 AbhÃ¤ngigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
openvpn (2.2.1-8+deb7u5) wird eingerichtet ...
[ ok ] Restarting virtual private network daemon.:.
insserv: Script nginx is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von openvpn (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurÃ¼ck
sudo (1.8.5p2-1+nmu3+deb7u4) wird eingerichtet ...
insserv: Script nginx is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von sudo (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurÃ¼ck
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 mysql-server-5.5
 php5-fpm
 rpcbind
 memcached
 mysql-server
 nginx-common
 nginx-full
 openvpn
 sudo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Sorry for the German language in there! The key lines are English, I think.

So, I think, the key problem is this:

```
insserv: Script nginx is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
```

But as nothing is said about a line or even a file with the missing piece, I am kind of clueless and seek for help! As far as I researched, it may be more a problem of php5-fpm instead of nginx (as I said, html sites can be accessed perfectly).
Can you give me a hint on how to solve this or has solved such an issue before?